# Update width and height of rectangle dynamically

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, svg, jointjs

I am trying to add rectangle to parent rect on clicking submit. I want the height of parent rect increase on adding new rectangle to parent so that it looks like child element resides with in parent like this:

```
$('.modeler_add_button').click(function (e)
{
    var parentValues = parent1.getBBox();
    var parentHeight = parentValues.height;
//    parent1.attr('height', parentHeight+25);
//    parent1.prop('height', parentHeight+25);
    parent1.set('height', parentHeight + 25);

    var newRect = new joint.shapes.tm.Actor({
        isInteractive: false,
        position: {x: pos.x + 1, y: pos.y + 25},
        size: {width: 120, height: 25},
        attrs: {
            text: {text: 'res', fill: 'black', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': 12},
            rect: {
                fill: '#F1F1F1', rx: 7, ry: 15, opacity: .80, 'stroke-width': 0, stroke: '#fff'
            }
        }
    });
    parent1.embed(newRect);
    graph.addCells([newRect]);
});
```

I tried with `element.set` and `element.attr` and `element.prop` methods which didn't work. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you think you could add this into a working fiddle so that we can have a play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using [`resize()`](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:resize) method of jointjs.

Comment: It would be a better answer if you showed how you used resize in your particular case.